# how to remove class when another button with same class is clicked javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of buttons with the same class, when a button is clicked I would like it to have an active class and when another button is clicked I would like the class (active) of the previous clicked button to be removed. Is there a way of doing this? I have thought of adding classList.toggle but this doesn't work.

```
<button class="helpBtn active">Help</button>
<button class="helpBtn">Help</button>
<button class="helpBtn">Help</button>

const helpBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.helpBtn');

 for (let i = 0; i < helpBtn.length; i++) {
             
                    helpBtn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                        helpBtn[i].classList.toggle("active");
                      })
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to just iterate all buttons and remove the CSS class unless the button is the clicked button and the button didn't have the class yet:

```js
const helpBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.helpBtn');
for (let btn of helpBtn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for (let other of helpBtn) {
            other.classList.toggle("active", other === btn && undefined);
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.active { background: lime }
```

```html
<button class="helpBtn active">Help</button>
<button class="helpBtn">Help</button>
<button class="helpBtn">Help</button>
```

Comment: sadly toggle doesn't work

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to query with the css selector of ".helpBtn.active" and remove the active class, before adding the active class to the btn which triggered the handler? ( `this.classList.add('active')` )

Comment: I tried using "this" but it said that "this" was undefined

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. Did you run the snippet I posted? Did you find anything wrong with how it runs? When I run it, the button I click gets the active CSS class, and the others don't. When I click another, it gets the active class instead. When I click the button that already has the active class, it is toggled. Is there something else you expected?

Comment: I ran it, it doesn't do anything, it doesn't like toggle. If I add classless.remove it works and removes the div but won't work for toggle.

Comment: Really? Are you running the snippet as it is *in my answer*, using the `Run code snippet` button? Which browser are you using? I don't understand "removes the div". There is nothing in my code that removes any div, and I don't see any requirement of removal in your question. What does "doesn't like toggle" mean? [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) is supported in all current browsers... All browsers "like" it.

Comment: I suspect you are not running my snippet, but have copied code into your own project where it doesn't do what you expect because of the larger context it runs in. If so, can you link to a fiddle (like jsfiddle.net) where the problem is reproducible? I can then check and tell you what is wrong.

Comment: thank you for your help, I will just try and work at it myself

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this is to Use the following code.
First we get a list of elements that have both the class `active` and `helpBtn` and remove the active class (This scheme you have, as mentioned will only ever have a single button active, so you could probably do away with the querySelectorAll and the forEach on its result)
Next, simply add the active class to the button which triggered the handler.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt) {
  let helpBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.helpBtn');
  helpBtns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', onHelpBtnClick, false));
}

function onHelpBtnClick(evt) {
  let activeHelpBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.helpBtn.active');
  activeHelpBtns.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
  this.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.helpBtn.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button class="helpBtn active">Help</button>
<button class="helpBtn">Help</button>
<button class="helpBtn">Help</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this , make the button a link and add the active class to the parent:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <style>
                    .menu li {
                        display: inline;
                        margin: 15px;
                    }

                    .active {
                        background-color: #20BF55;
                        padding: 5px;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>

            <body>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <script>
                    let a = document.querySelectorAll(".menu a");
                    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                        a[i].onclick = function () {
                            let b = document.querySelector(".menu li.active");
                            b.classList.remove("active");
                            this.parentNode.classList.add('active');
                        };
                    }

                </script>
            </body>

            </html>
```